# How to MD5 encrypt using Challenge Key

Tags: c#, authentication, encryption, md5, challenge-response

I am trying to establish a connection to a Server using MD5 Authentication.
The server returns me the challenge key. 
How can I use it to encrypt my password and send it back to the server.
The encryption method currently I know needs Password Hash, Salt Key, and VI Code.
How Can I make it .

```
    static readonly string PasswordHash = "PasswordHash";
    static readonly string SaltKey = "SaltKey";
    static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
        var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

        byte[] cipherTextBytes;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
```

Comment: Can you make more clear what you need to do? Usually you just have to use the challange key + your password to create the md5 hash, and then send it back to the server ... but I'm not sure that's what you are looking for

Comment: To be blunt whatever you're trying to implement sucks. Simply 1) Get a trash can 2) Put all of that crypto code in 3) Get SSL instead